# Problem with dots on macos mojave

Tags: macos, imac, mojave

I updated my iMac and now I get dark blue and light blue color on the “dots” to close fullscreen instead of the normal green, yellow and red dots.

Can someone help me or this is or is this how the new OS looks?

[image]

Comment: Two things to test. 1) Post a screenshot as well as your photo. 2) Check Displays control panel > Colour & make sure you have the correct profile chosen. Try a few different ones & see if they make any significant difference.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. The color shift doesn't only affect the close and minimize controls, some icons (but not all) have an unusual appearance, for example "Displays" has an orange tint while "Mission Control" looks ok. I've noticed from your photo that the glass panel has been removed, could that be the problem?

Comment: You could possibly have Invert Colours on. Try going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Accessibility → Invert Colors and check the box next to it. Then try doing command + option + control + 8. [Article](https://9to5mac.com/2019/05/24/invert-display-colors-mac/)

Comment: The background looks like it could be inverted, but everything else in the interface looks to have a hue shift. It's true that in terms of hue, inverted colors would give you similar results, but it's not inverted. To my knowledge, Mac OS doesn't have the smart invert feature like on IOS? There are many examples, but perhaps the best one is the window shadow, which is always black and should be white with invert on. Another good example is every icon that has white color... None of the icons ever change, not even with dark mode on, yet the white mouse icon is still white in the photo.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer space as somewhere to park the image for now…

It looks  like you have a 180° Hue shift. I can achieve the same intentionally in Photoshop by doing that - note how it also affects all the icon colours in the same way too.

[image]

Two things to test.

1. Post a screenshot as well as your photo, to check whether it looks the same [hardware test].
2. Check Displays > Colour & make sure you have the correct profile chosen. Try a few different ones & see if they make any significant difference.

*From comments above - & I had already tested this before posting this answer…*
It doesn't look like Accessibility Colour Inversion, because even if you're set to Dark Mode, most of the Control Panel will look similar to these images, but icons such as Mouse would have turned black.